# Jquery input checkbox checked value to array cleaner output

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I've got a table, each with checkbox, that if checked, remove the data of the checked, with a check all box on the top (just like phpmyadmin for example).

var_dump the checked result gave me this:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "on"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "vVZW9qrG"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "8N5Go5J2"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "mNY6nYXK"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "8w5DzY0M"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "KJZNVZxA"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "1J5REq0v"
  [7]=>
  string(8) "wEYejqQV"
  [8]=>
  string(8) "Nmqw7qMR"
  [9]=>
  string(8) "ea5MXqGl"
}
```

which is almost what I want, except that on key `0` there is `on` value, I'm guessing it's from the check all box. How to remove that `on` value? (Normally I would just `splice` that value, but I need a cleaner one, because there will be a case where check all box won't be checked)

This is how I got the checked value (in CS):

```
val = $('#categoryList input:checkbox:checked').map(->
    $(this).val()
).get()
```

`console.log(val)` gave me the above result

Comment: add a class `root` to your `check all` checkbox and filter this `root` class out in your selector

Comment: something like `$('#categoryList input:checkbox:checked').not('.root').map(->
    $(this).val()
).get()` ?

Comment: yup check you console output for the result